# CodeIgniter TEXT to Variable Data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working with CodeIgniter Framework, and I am wondering if there is any way that I could use a String or Text into variables data.

**Example**

**MODEL / HELPER / LIBRARY DECLARATION**

```
$config['title'] = "SOME TITLE HERE";
CONST('title', "SOME TITLE HERE";
$title = "SOME TITLE HERE";
```

**HTML / PHP**

```
<h1>{title}</h1>
```

**OUTPUT**

## SOME TITLE HERE

Hope you get what I mean :D

Thank you.

Comment: could you more explain what you want to do ?

Comment: I want something that echo a {elapsed_time} variables like custom like this.

Comment: Now I get it. $this->load->library('parser');

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `application/config/constant.php` file and set

```
define('title','SOME TITLE HERE');
```

And you can use `title` using

```
<h1><?php echo title;?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I get it now. thanks for all you reply!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{blog_title}</title>

    </head>
    <body>

    <h3>{blog_heading}</h3>

    {blog_entries}
    <h5>{title}</h5>
    <p>{body}</p>
    {/blog_entries}
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Class**

```
    $this->load->library('parser');
```

**Array Content**

```
$this->load->library('parser');

$data = array(
            'blog_title' => 'My Blog Title',
            'blog_heading' => 'My Blog Heading'
            );

$this->parser->parse('blog_template', $data);
```